# In "I wonder what he is", what is what?

Tags: vocabulary

I wonder ***what*** he is. 
([Random House Dictionary's #2](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/what?s=t), not from the linked online-version but from its paper version)

I suppose the sentence would mean ‘I wonder what sort [type] of person he is’ as [Mister StoneyB](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/27148/who-and-what-somebody-is) says.  But the Korean translating version of the dictionary interprets it as: ‘*I wonder what job he does*’ or ‘*I wonder from where he comes*’. Could the translating version’s interpretation be proper?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends, really, on the context.

> John says he's a constant volunteer at the soup kitchen, but he makes very cruel jokes about poor people. I wonder what he is.
>
> He's very knowledgeable about New Historicist literary theory, but he dresses like a man making seven figures. I wonder what he is.
>
> He looks Oriental, but he speaks with a German accent. I wonder what he is.
>
> Is it a bird? Is it a plane? It's Superman! --no, he just fell out of the sky. I wonder what he is - or was.

Comment: Is "no, it he just fell out of the sky", "no, it (is) he just fell out of the sky"?

Comment: @Listenever Oops. You are now qualified to teach English 101 to college freshmen!